# Highlight entire week date in jquery datepicker based on the selected dates

Tags: jquery

Hello all I have written a script which is working fine, but what I need is I would like to highlight all the dates which are available in the textboxes, here is the working fiddle. When I choose previous week the dates under those range should be highlighted and they are getting highlighted when I click any date manually.

Also I need the day to be started from Monday instead of sunday, I tired by setting `firstDay: 1` but the selection is not working as expected.

https://jsfiddle.net/DorababuMeka/6xzrqcpq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a function to highlight the week that contains the starting date in the supplied textbox:

https://jsfiddle.net/6xzrqcpq/20/

`highlightWeek()` is simply using the calendar selector and iterating through each `tr` and `td` and comparing the date value in the current `a` tag to the date in the starting date textbox. Function is only called on `prev()` and `next()` but can be adjusted per your needs. Good luck.

```
function prev() {
  // alert("previous clicked");
  var dt = new Date($('#weekStartDate').val());
  dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 7); // subtract 7 days
  $('#weekStartDate').val($.date(dt));

  var enddt = new Date($('#weekEndDate').val());
  enddt.setDate(enddt.getDate() - 7); // subtract 7 days
  $('#weekEndDate').val($.date(enddt));

  highlightWeek();
}

function next() {
  //alert("next clicked");
  var dt = new Date($('#weekStartDate').val());
  dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 7); // add 7 days
  $('#weekStartDate').val($.date(dt));

  var enddt = new Date($('#weekEndDate').val());
  enddt.setDate(enddt.getDate() + 7); // add 7 days
  $('#weekEndDate').val($.date(enddt));

  highlightWeek();
}

function highlightWeek() {
    var clkDt = new Date($('#weekStartDate').val());
  var clickDay = clkDt.getDate(); //this is the value we want to select in cal  
  $('.ui-datepicker-calendar > tbody > tr').each(function(){
    $(this).children('td').each(function(){
        var dy = $(this).first('a');
      if(dy.text() == clickDay){
        dy.click();
      }      
    });     
  });
}
```

Comment: I updated the `datepicker` options to fix the 'firstDay' item as well, see it set to Monday here: https://jsfiddle.net/6xzrqcpq/21/

Comment: Hi one small issue when we click on previous and next the month change is not working as expected. It is always in the February Month if it was selected

Comment: The date is selecting sunday as start day

Comment: Check this I set to Monday as my first day and when I move to `April` on clicking next it is not moving to `May` https://jsfiddle.net/DorababuMeka/6xzrqcpq/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already knew how to get Starting Date (startDate) and Ending Date (endingDate) after selecting a week on Week/Datepicker.
Here is an easier approach:

### JS

```
beforeShowDay:function(date) {
    // Save [startDate] and [endDate] variable at @onSelect
    let start = new Date(Date.parse(startDate));
    let end = new Date(Date.parse(endDate));
    if (date >= start && date <= end) {
         cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
    }
    // Add cssClass to days within selected week range
    return [true, cssClass];
}
```

### CSS

```
#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-current-day a { 
    border: 1px solid white ; background: springgreen; font-weight: bold; color: white; 
}
```